# ChartJS not showing from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, xampp, chart.js

**PHP: chart_db.php**

```
<?php
require_once ('dbh.inc.php');

$JSON_Response = array();

//Counts the number of Active
$count_active = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT client_id FROM client WHERE status = 1");
$JSON_Response['active'] = mysqli_num_rows($count_active);

//Counts the number of Inactive
$count_inactive = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT client_id FROM client WHERE status = 0");
$JSON_Response['inactive'] = mysqli_num_rows($count_inactive);

error_log('hello');
echo json_encode($JSON_Response);

?>
```

**JS: chart.js**
    $(document).ready(function(){

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/FAME/private/includes/chart_db.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(response){

            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            var activeData = text(data.active);
            var inactiveData = text(data.inactive);
            console.log(activeData);

            var ctx = document.getElementById('piechart').getContext('2d');
            var statusChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Active', 'Inactive'],
                    datasets: [{ 
                        pointStyle: 'circle',
                        backgroundColor: [ 'rgb(78, 115, 223)', 'rgb(25, 179, 211)' ],
                        data: activeData, inactiveData
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    segmentShowStroke: false,
                    cutoutPercentage: 70,
                    legend: {
                        onClick: false,
                        position: 'bottom',
                        labels: {
                            usePointStyle: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Question:** The problem is that in the data in chart are not showing. The entire chart is not showing. And with the log from chrome inspection: it says that there is an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with php, mysql or xampp. You are using an undefined method called `text`. The error message says it all. Check your third and fourth lines in the ajax success. You have:

```
var activeData = text(data.active);
```

Replace it with :

```
var activeData = data.active;
```

and see what happens.